# How do I render a component when a button is clicked in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am just starting to learn ReactNative and I cant seem to find the pertinent info on their tutorials page.

I have a list which is rendered on the page, each item in the list has an info button. When the info button is clicked, I want to render a new screen (component) which displays additional information about the item.

`items-list.component.js`:

```
render: function() {
        let content;

        if (this.state.dataSource._cachedRowCount > 0) {
            // console.log('data render list')
            content = (<View style={styles.container}>
                            <View style={globalStyles.header}>                     
                                <Text style={globalStyles.headerText}>Calls History</Text>
                                <Icon name="plus" size={24} color="#fff" style={{marginRight: 4}}/>                            
                            </View>

                            <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                                      renderRow={this.renderRow}>
                            </ListView>
                        </View>);
        } else {
            content = (<View><LoadingAnimation></LoadingAnimation></View>);
        }
        return (<View style={styles.container}>{content}</View>);
    },


renderRow(rowData) {

                //row contains item name, image displayed here:


                <Image source = {{uri: rowData.peers[0].avatar}}
                       style={globalStyles.avatar} />
               <View style ={styles.container}>       
                    <Text style={styles.nameText} numberOfLines={1}>{rowData.peer}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.rowText} numberOfLines={1}>{rowData.ts.date}</Text>                     
                </View>      

                 <TouchableHighlight onPress ={() =>  <CallsInfo callsData={rowData}/> }> 
                     <Icon name="information" size={24} color="#9e9e9e" style={styles.rowIcon}/>

                </TouchableHighlight>
```

`calls-info.js`:

```
var React = require('react-native');


var MyButton = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.callsData}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  },
});
```

What I want to do is when the `TouchableHighLight` is pressed, the user is taken to a new screen with the data passed to it.

I tried to do this on my own by passing `CallsInfo`, which is a component, to the button, but when I click it, nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good [article](https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.5eh79kkn7) about it.

You need to use [navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) object to transition between different scenes in your app.

e.g in your App.js, renderScene can look like this:

```
renderScene(route) {
  return (
    <View style={[route.style]}>
       <route.Page extras={route.props} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

And you can attach onPress handler with the following logic

```
onChangeRoute() {
 this.navigator.push({Page: YourComponent, props: yourprops});
}
```

So your component will have an access to extras props by using:

```
this.props.extras in YourComponent
```